# SlimFrameworrk só acessa duplicando barras na URL

Tags: php, framework, slim, slimframework

Estou usando o SlimFramework e tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<?php   

    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
    use Slim\Http\UploadedFile;

     $mid01 = function(Request $request, Response $response, $next):      Response{

        $response->getBody()->write("BEFORE<br>");
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        $response->getBody()->write("AFTER<br>");

        return $response;

    };

    $app = new \Slim\App();

     $app->post('/file', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
        
        $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        $response->getBody()->write("API<br>");
        return $response;

    })->add($mid01);

    $app->run();
```

Aí, executo o seguinte comando para iniciar o servidor:

```
/var/www/apiFiles/api$ php -S 0.0.0.0:3131 -t src ./src/api.php
```

O Servidor inicia normalmente e consigo dar um POST através de um hostname, como:

```
api.empresaXXX.com.br:3131
```

A questão é, quando tento acessar a rota `http://api.empresaXXX.com.br:3131/file`, recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: slimError1]

Porém, se eu der um POST em `http://api.empresaXXX.com.br:3131//file`, duplicando as barras, ele acessa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão de como posso proceder neste caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a solução para o problema.

Aparentemente o Slim necessita que o arquivo do servidor tenha o nome de:

```
index.php
```

Alterei para index.php e rodei o comando:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:3131 -t src src/index.php
```

Funcionou!